# Função recursiva que retorna a soma dos dígitos de um número

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Preciso criar uma função recursiva que recebe um número `n` inteiro e retorna a soma dos dígitos deste número.

Fiz o seguinte código mas está dando `None`:

```
def somadig(n, s = 0):
    if n > 10:
       d = n%10
       s += d
       return somadig(n//10,s)


print(somadig(120))
```

Comment: Neste caso o resultado seria 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não está tratando a saída corretamente. Quando `n` chegar em 0 deve retornar 0, caso contrário deve fazer a conta e provocar a recursividade. Tem variáveis e passos demais no código, trabalhe com a soma diretamente em vez de guardar em variável e passar novamente, simplificando:

```
def somadig(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (n % 10) + somadig(n // 10)

print(somadig(120))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JhxzHw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pzbxkito-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/RecursiveCondition.py).

O seu dava `None` porque se a condição do `if` for falsa não passa por um `return`, portanto ele retorna nada.

Comment: Nossa obrigado, eu não sabia que dava para passar no return uma expressão de soma com a função

Comment: Pode passar qualquer expressão, e isto é generalizado na linguagem, na verdade são poucos lugares onde não cabe uma expressão qualquer, mas onde cabe uma, sempre pode qualquer.